# Internals, InternalsVisibleTo and testing shared behavior

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, internal, vstest

We have a shared basic interface `public interface IOperation {...}` and lots (tens, soon 100+) different objects that implement `IOperation`.

We also have tests for all those implementations, all inheriting from base classes called `TestOperationCommon`  that are templated with the actual operations class and types for a Create method to `new` such an operation. We have implementations for TestOperationCommon with one up to five template parameters (which is enough for all operations).

Now, recently it was decided to make all operation implementations internal and only have `IOperation` public, which seems like a good idea as those ops are implementation details. And with `[InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` testing seemed solved, too.

However, now I see that we cannot use our test structure anymore, as the generic parameters to the public test class are now internal (at least the actual class under test is), which leads to

`Inconsistent Accessibility .... less accessible than ...`

errors. The code below, a public test class cannot inherit from TestOperationCommon with a generic parameter T that is internal. But duplicating all those shared-behavior tests into the specific tests also seems like a bad idea.

- Is there a way to get the vstest framework (VS2013+) to test `[TestClass]`es that are internal?
- Or is there another way we can keep the shared tests without having to duplicate lots of code?
- Or are we doing it wrong (making those 'implementation detail-classes` internal)?

Code example as request in comment:

```
public interface IOperation { ... }

internal class SomeOperation : IOperation 
{
    public SomeOperation(A a, B b, C c) {...}
}


public abstract TestOperationCommon<T, A, B, C> 
    where T : IOperation
    where ...
{
    protected abstract T Create(A a, B b, C c);

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCommonOperationBehavior()
    {
        var op = Create(Mock.Of<A>(), Mock.Of<B>(), Mock.Of<C>);
        ...
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestSomeOperation : TestOperationCommon<SomeOperation, ...>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSpecificSomeOperationStuff() {}

}
```

Comment: small example with code will help a lot

Comment: Hmm, the usual point of such a big refactoring is to substantially reduce the test effort.  Since there is no point in testing anything that normal client code cannot use anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Could you creating a test wrapper class?

Something like:

```
[TestClass]
public class AnnoyingTestSomeOperationWrapper
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSpecificSomeOperationStuff() 
    {
        new TestSomeOperation().TestSpecificSomeOperationStuff()
    }

}

internal class TestSomeOperation : TestOperationCommon<SomeOperation, ...>
{
    public void TestSpecificSomeOperationStuff() {}

}
```

Comment: I tried that, the main problem is that either it's ugly or we don't get nice test failure messages. If we forward all six methods (each in their own [TestMethod], we have lots of duplication. And if we just create one method which calls all of the shared methods, we lots the nice failures that lead us exactly to the problem.

Comment: I was trying to figure out if you could use ILGen/Code Generation to auto create the wrapper classes for you but I doubt it'll play nicely with the VS Test Runner.